# laravel localization using mcamara package

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-localization

i am trying to use laravel mcamara package for automatic language translation from the language files. the package supposed to be working in this way:

when i access the website for example from France and i configured french language in the package configuration file then it should be redirected to this url by default: [www.example.com/fr](http://www.example.com/fr) and if i am accessing it from italy and i configured italian language then it should show: [www.example.com/it](http://www.example.com/it) below is my code for redirecting it to the exact locale but it's not working automatically:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]], function(){ all the routes of my application is here });
```

Answer (score 1):

at first yoy will need to detect user country by ip  can use this package https://github.com/stevebauman/location , and set at **boot** function inside **App\Providers\AppServiceProvider**

```
       public function boot()
       {
         $ip = request()->getClientIp(); 
         $position = \Location::get($ip); 
         \LaravelLocalization::setLocale($position->countryCode); 
       }
```

and replace prefix at route group to be :

```
     \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale();
```

route group should be :

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() , 'middleware' => ['localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]], function(){ all the routes of my application is here });
```

Comment: i want to do it through package and not manually. i think i am missing something. i did exactly what the package instructed.

Comment: you can use this package to detect user country  https://github.com/stevebauman/location
and update boot function to be 

                  $ip = request()->getClientIp();
    $position = \Location::get($ip); 
                  \LaravelLocalization::setLocale($position->countryCode);

Comment: i installed the package but as you said request->getClientIp() giving me localhost address 127.0.0.1and then it's not working in the get method of the package.

Comment: package may dont work perfect at localhot , because the its local ip 127.0.0.1 it will work perfect on production , 
you can try dummy ips at local : 
151.97.106.161(italy)
66.249.75.9 (france) 
and when you on production use request->getClientIp()

Comment: by adding getCurrentLocale() in the route group prefix, i am getting 404 not found on root url